# ReportViewer 14: "The primary reference [...] could not be resolved" while targeting .NET Framework 4.0

Tags: .net, reference, .net-4.0, reportviewer, nuget-package

I've installed the ReportViewer 14 NuGet package in my Windows Forms Application (targeting .NET Framwork 4.0): [Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms) (V. 140.340.80; latest stable)

When building, I'm receiving several warnings similar to the following:

> The primary reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the assembly "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.14.0, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which was built against the ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" framework. This is a higher version than the currently targeted framework ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0".

The application builds successfully and everything seems to work, but I'm a still little concerned about the warnings.

I'm not sure if it's related to the OS, but: I am running Windows 7, my coworkers are on Windows 10 and are not seeing the issue (both Visual Studio 2017)

Unfortunately, we're currently tied to .NET Framework 4.0, because we have to support some Windows XP clients.

**Update:**

I created a new, empty .NET 4.0 project and am receiving the same, but fewer warnings (this time only affecting "*[.NET] Framework assemblies*").

Here is the full list of warnings from the vanilla project:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1987,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1987,5): warning MSB3258: The primary reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the .NET Framework assembly "Microsoft.Build.Framework, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which has a higher version "14.0.0.0" than the version "4.0.0.0" in the current target framework.
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1987,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1987,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Threading.Tasks, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Threading.Tasks, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1987,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Diagnostics.Tracing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Diagnostics.Tracing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1987,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Collections.Concurrent, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Collections.Concurrent, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1987,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Dynamic.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Dynamic.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1987,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Collections, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Collections, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1987,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Threading, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Threading, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1987,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Resources.ResourceManager, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Resources.ResourceManager, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1987,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Globalization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Globalization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1987,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Diagnostics.Debug, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Diagnostics.Debug, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1987,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1987,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1987,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Diagnostics.Tools, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Diagnostics.Tools, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1987,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Reflection, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Reflection, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
```

Comment: Having the same issue here. .NET 4 WPF project, replaced ReportViewer version 11 with 14 (or 140 as the package says). I wouldn't even go replacing it if report designer extension for VS 2017 didn't update the RDLC XML with a new version...

Comment: @jl. I finally found a solution that works for me (see my answer below). Could you please confirm if this works for you as well?

Comment: I updated my project to .net 4.5 in the mean time since it was about time anyway. Will try an older branch later tonight hopefully. I'll try removing VS 2015 since I don't use it anymore.

Comment: Yup, removing VS 2015 fixed the warnings. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to resolve it:

### TL;DR

The core problem seemed to be the installation of *Visual Studio 2015* respectively *SQL Server Management Studio 17.2*: After uninstalling all of it's components, the warnings were gone!

### Long answer

The first thing I noticed was, that the assemblies MSBuild complained about (e.g. `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.14.0`) were installed in my Global Assembly Cache (GAC) whereas they weren't on my colleagues PC's. I verified that by running the following in the Developer Command Prompt:

```
gacutil /l Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.14.0
```

So something must have had installed these assemblies in the GAC.

The version number "14" pointed in the direction of Visual Studio 2015 (because its internal version number is Visual Studio v14). So I uninstalled everything that had "Visual Studio 2015" in its name - including

- Visual Studio 2015 Shell (isolated) and
- SQL Server Management Studio 17.2 (because I knew that SSMS is basically a Visual Studio extension and is installing the "Shell"-Version of VS alongside)

**This resolved all of the warnings.**

(I assume MSBuild is then using the Reference Assemblies, which are suitable for .NET 4.0 rather than those from the GAC that were targeting 4.5)

To double-check my findings I reinstalled SQL Server Management Studio 17.2, which includes *VS2015 Shell (isolated)* - and the warnings returned.
After uninstalling it one more time, they were gone again.

This is not a completely satisfying solution though, because I can't install SSMS anymore.

Comment: perhaps link to the original thread in the [ms support forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/21fd273d-8f2b-41cf-adf7-dd7506e57e43/msbuild-referencing-assemblies-with-wrong-target-framework-version-warning-msb3275-warning?forum=msbuild) question.

Comment: this thread on SO is actually the "original" one. After it couldn't attract any answers for a week, I also posted on the msdn forums.Since it's my own work and the other thread doesn't really provide any additional value, I thought it's not really necessary to share a link :)

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed this by removing all reference to "Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design"

(This reference is added by the report viewer NuGet package. In VS2010/VS2015 I've never used that reference nor distributed that dll in my apps.)

So the solution for me was the following:

- VS 2017, SSMS 17.x both installed
- Winform application targeting .net 4.0
- Added report viewer nugget package and "Microsoft rdlc reports designer for visual studio" extension
- Manually delete Microsoft.RepotViewer.Design reference
- My application contains only local reports: rdlc files with old format (vs2010), and some revised ones, converted to the latest rdlc by VS report designer.
- App compiles fine without warnings, and runs without any issue on dev machine.
- My WIX installer installs only these reporting related components: Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common.dll, Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization.dll, Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel.dll, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms.dll, Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll

Tested on win10 without any issues.

Stress tested on a clean XP SP3 with .net 4.0: reports running fine.